# Add X in a column corresponding to given name automatically when new row is added to shared sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create something, which will be able to automatically add X in a given column to newly created row in a shared google sheet. The sheet is my work schedule and every row represents a task. Each task has a limit of people and right now there are plenty people in my project and since I'm working on laptop and I don't have external screen it's almost impossible for me to sign up for anything (since sheet is wide and it takes time to find mine column).
I was thinking about creating an Apps Script with onEvent() listener, but everyone would see a new script and I don't think that I got permissions to add a new script to the sheet anyway.

Do you have any ideas what could I do to achieve my goal?

Best regards,
Ed.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Since you have edit access to the spreadsheet, you also have access to its bound script projects, but there is no `onEvent()` listener in Apps Script. Further, it is unclear what `X` is and how it would help solve the issue.

Comment: I don't understand clearly what you mean.  It would be helpful if you included a minimal example of data before as well as an example of your desired result. Also clarify what you are trying to add instead of *"something"*.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue seems to be that in a large spreadsheet it is difficult to locate the intersection of a row that is labeled with a specific task name and a column that is labeled with a specific name.

Assuming that task names are in column `A` and people's names are in row `1`, choose **View > Freeze > 1 row** and **1 column** to keep those names always visible. As you move around the sheet, the row number next to the task name column gets automatically highlighted, and so does the column label on top of the person's name. Use these visual cues to track where you are.